# On click effect (CSS, HTML, JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know how to get "onclick" effect. I mean how to open new site by click menu. Below i attached example. Please tell what can i do.

https://bslthemes.com/ryan/demo/index-new-no-photo.htm

Comment: Explain in detail what you need, what you tried and what resulted. The link results in 404.

Comment: sorry i forget about "l"

https://bslthemes.com/ryan/demo/index-new-no-photo.html

Answer (score 2):

With addEventListener you have an univerdal method to respond on the click event. Instead of `<div>` you may use `<button>` or any other element, that's up to you.

```
<div id="whatever">Click me</div>

<script>
document.querySelector("#whatever").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/");
});
</script>
```